# Enter to git CI termial and list the directories

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to git ci/cd. I have created a gitlab-ci.yml file. This file downloads a tar file and tries to move those files to one more directory to perform some test.

So I want to check whether files and directories are getting created. Is there any way to enter to git terminal or something and go to a path and list all the files?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since the yml file works with commands, you can do something as such.

```
test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd <the target directory> #navigates to the path you want
    - dir #lists all files
```

From here, you could create a test to check the count of files vs the actual count with some basic cmd logic.

Here is a good resource with all the cmd commands https://ss64.com/nt/.